# updating data in same mysql table using trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a mysql table,  QuotationPrt. I want to create following trigger

```
DECLARE TOTAL FLOAT;
DECLARE QTY FLOAT; 
DECLARE UNITCOST FLOAT;
DECLARE OPERATIONCOST FLOAT; 
DECLARE TOOLINGCOST FLOAT; 

SELECT QUOTATIONPRT.QTY,QUOTATIONPRT.UNITPRICE,QUOTATIONPRT.OPERATIONCOST,QUOTATIONPRT.TOOLINGCOST INTO QTY,UNITCOST,OPERATIONCOST,TOOLINGCOST FROM QUOTATIONPRT WHERE QUOTATIONPRTID=OLD.QUOTATIONPRTID;

SET TOTAL=(QTY*UNITCOST)+OPERATIONCOST+TOOLINGCOST;

UPDATE QUOTATIONPRT SET QUOTATIONPRT.TOTAL=TOTAL WHERE QUOTATIONPRT.QUOTATIONPRTID=OLD.QUOTATIONPRTID;

END
```

This should update quotationprt's TOTAL column. But when I try to update data in quotationprt table it gives error and data is not updated. It might be possible that I have written trigger after data is updated and try to update the same table.

So is there any way buy which I could update the TOTAL column?

Comment: Could you please add the details of the error ?

Comment: Please add the create trigger statement.

Comment: You cannot action a table which fired a trigger but you can amend OLD. and NEW. values.

Comment: @P.Salmon : #1442 - Can't update table 'quotationprt' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

Comment: My previous comment applies.

Comment: that's what I need to know how to use that old. and new. values. If you can help me out it will help me in many of the tables.

Comment: You didn't add the create statement - it would be better if you added the complete trigger not just a segment of it.

Comment: There are examples of how to use and  set OLD. and New. Values in the docs https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER `trg_upd` AFTER UPDATE ON `quotationprt`
 FOR EACH ROW begin
DECLARE TOTAL FLOAT;
DECLARE QTY FLOAT; 
DECLARE UNITCOST FLOAT;
DECLARE OPERATIONCOST FLOAT; 
DECLARE TOOLINGCOST FLOAT; 

SELECT QUOTATIONPRT.ANNUALQTY,QUOTATIONPRT.UNITCOST,QUOTATIONPRT.OPERATIONCOST,QUOTATIONPRT.TOOLINGCOST INTO QTY,UNITCOST,OPERATIONCOST,TOOLINGCOST FROM QUOTATIONPRT WHERE QUOTATIONPRT.QUOTATIONPRTID=new.QUOTATIONPRTID;

SET TOTAL=(QTY*UNITCOST)+OPERATIONCOST+TOOLINGCOST;

UPDATE QUOTATIONPRT SET QUOTATIONPRT.TOTAL=TOTAL WHERE QUOTATIONPRT.QUOTATIONPRTID=new.QUOTATIONPRTID;

END